# How to make Next-Auth-session-token-dependent server queries with React Query in Next JS?

Tags: next.js, react-query, next-auth

I am trying to make an API GET request, using React Query's useInfiniteQuery hook, that uses data from a Next Auth session token in the query string.

I have a callback in `/api/auth/[...nextauth.ts]` to send extra `userData` to my session token.

There are two relevant pages on the client side. Let's call them `/pages/index.tsx` and `/hooks/useApiData.ts`. This is what they look like, for all intents and purposes:

```js
// pages/index.tsx

export default function Page() {
   const {data, fetchNextPage, isLoading, isError} = useCourseData()

   if (isLoading) return <main />

   return <main>
      <InfiniteScroller fetchMore={fetchNextPage}>
         {data?.pages?.map(page => page?.results?.map(item: string => item))}
      </InfiniteScroller>
   </main>
}
```

```js
// hooks/useApiData.ts

async function fetchPage(pageParam: string) {
   const response = await fetch(pageParam)
   return await response.json()
}

export default function useApiData() {
   const {data: session} = useSession()

   const init = `/api?userData=${session?.user?.userData}`
   
   return useInfiniteQuery('query',
      ({pageParam = init}) => fetchPage(pageParam),
      {getNextPageParam: prevPage => prevPage.next ?? undefined}
   )
}
```

My initial request gets sent to the API as `/api?userData=undefined`. The extra data is definitely making its way into the token.

I can place the data from my session in the DOM via the render function of `/pages/index.tsx`, so I figure the problem is something to do with custom hooks running before the session context is ready, or something like that... I don't understand the mechanics of hooks well enough to figure that out.

I've been looking for answers for a long time, and I'm surprised not to have found a single person with the same issue. These are not unpopular packages and I guess a lot of people are using them in conjunction to achieve what I'm attempting here, so I figure I must be doing something especially dumb. But what?!

How can I get the data from my Next Auth session into my React Query request? And for bonus points, why is the session data not available when the request is sent in my custom hook?

Comment: You can use the `enabled` option on the `useInfiniteQuery` call to only run the query when the user's session data is available, e.g. `{ enabled: !!session?.user?.userData }`. See https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/dependent-queries.

Comment: Oh, awesome. I'm going to check that out. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, that was no use - it only enables/disables **re-fetching** of data, so the first query still gets sent. Thanks for your response, all the same.